# "music composer" vs "musical composer"

Tags: differences, adjectives, suffixes, compounds

A UK guy told me that Mozart was a *musical composer*.
A US guy told me that Mozart was a *music composer*.

Is it a regional difference?

Comment: *Musical* as an adjective usually implies *melodic, lyrical*, which you'd probably only want to use here if you were contrasting Mozart with "atonal" composers such as Arnold Schoenberg, John Cage, etc. But it's also a noun, which would be accurately used adjectivally (as a *noun adjunct*) in, say, *Andrew LLoyd-Webber is a musical composer*. In short, you should probably go for ***music composer*** unless you want to either ignore it completely (since by default, *what composers compose is **music***), or use the straightforward and unproblematic ***Mozart was a composer of music***.

Answer (score 5):

It may be a regional difference, but both adjectives are completely unnecessary.  Mozart was a composer.  People who compose music are called composers.

That being said, strange as it may seen, some compositions are considered more "musical" than others; i.e. melodious and harmonious.  But I've never heard a composer referred to as "musical" - only a composition.

A "musical" is also a specific type of theatrical performance, so one could say of a composer who is not well known, *he composes musicals.*

Comment: Your first sentence is exactly what I was thinking. By the way, welcome to the site! The only thing I think might make your answer better is a brief discussion of the construction "music composer", since right now you don't seem to mention it at all (aside from implying in the first sentence that it is redundant).