# When to use "music" & when to use "musical"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In [dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/musical_1?q=musical),

> [only before noun] connected with music; containing music
>
> the musical director of the show
>
> musical talent/ability/skill
>
> musical styles/tastes
>
> a musical production/entertainment
>
> musical instruments
>
> [music](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/music?q=music): the art of writing or playing music
>
> to study music
>
> a career in music
>
> music lessons
>
> the music business/industry

so, we got "**music industry**" but "**musical production**" & I heard people said "**musical life**"

Ok, The beautiful girl= the girl is beautiful

The musical life= the life is musical

My question is: why not "**musical industry**" or "**music production**" or "**music life**"?

Comment: If you type "music musical" in the [search box](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=music+musical), you will find two related Qs, one of which I linked in the above comment and the other is [“music composer” vs “musical composer”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363692/music-composer-vs-musical-composer), I know it is very confusing and it would be better if you could edit your question and explain why the linked questions don't help you. "Musical industry" sounds like an industry related with "musical": *a play or movie in which singing and dancing play an essential part*.

Comment: @Rathony Or an industry in which the workers sing beautifully as they toil.